# DataAnnotations dynamically attaching attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Apparently it is possible to dynamically attach DataAnnotation attributes to object properties at runtime and as such achieve dynamic validation.

Can someone provide code sample on this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

MVC has a hook to provide your own ModelValidatorProvider.  By default MVC 2 uses a sub class of ModelValidatorProvider called DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider that is able to use System.DataAnnotations.ComponentModel.ValidationAttribute attributes for validation.

The DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider uses reflection to find all the ValidationAttributes and simply loops through the collection to validate your models.  All you need to do is override a method called GetValidators and inject your own attributes from whichever source you choose.  I use this technique to do convention validations, the properties with DataType.Email attribute always gets passed through a regex, and use this technique to pull information from the database to apply more restrictive validations for "non-power" users.

The following example simply says "always make any FirstName properties required":

```
 public class CustomMetadataValidationProvider : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
 {
    protected override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
    {
        //go to db if you want
        //var repository = ((MyBaseController) context.Controller).RepositorySomething;

        //find user if you need it
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(metadata.PropertyName) && metadata.PropertyName == "FirstName")
            attributes = new List<Attribute>() {new RequiredAttribute()};

        return base.GetValidators(metadata, context, attributes);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is register the provider in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomMetadataValidationProvider());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

The end result:

[image: end result]

with this model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One problem with the example code in this answer is attributes can be processed twice: once by your subclass of `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` and once by the pre-existing one. This can lead to errors. I think it's better to only pass attributes that you're adding into the call to `base.GetValidators` to avoid this.

Comment: Also, in ASP.NET MVC 4 (and possibly others), `base.GetValidators` automatically adds `RequiredAttribute` when `metadata.IsRequired` is `true`. One way to circumvent this is to set `metadata.IsRequired` to `false` before calling `base.GetValidators`. You can set it back to the original value after the call.

Comment: I do not want to depend upon data annotation , we want to make it more generic validation please tell me is this approach useful?

Comment: I am getting compilation error `cannot convert from 'DynValidationMVC.CustomMetadataValidationProvider' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidatorProvider'` when adding in Global.asax file.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have added different namespace. After adding `System.Web.Mvc;`, it compiled. :-)

Answer (score 8):

In your global.asax you have to clear the ModelValidatorProviders before adding the new one. Otherwise it will add every annotation two times which will give you a "Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique."-error.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomMetadataValidationProvider());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using a custom `MetadataValidationProvider` with an overridden `GetValidators` has a few weaknesses:

- Some attributes such as `DisplayAttribute` aren't related to validation, so adding them at the validation stage doesn't work.
- It may not be future-proof; a framework update could cause it to stop working.

If you want your dynamically-applied data annotations to work consistently, you can subclass `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` and `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`. After doing this, *replace* the framework's ones via `ModelMetadataProviders.Current` and `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers` at application start-up. (You could do it in `Application_Start`.)

When you subclass the built-in providers, a systematic and hopefully future-proof way to apply your own attributes is to override `GetTypeDescriptor`. I've done this successfully, but it involved creating an implementation of `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and `PropertyDescriptor`, which required a lot of code and time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can add attributes to members at runtime, but you could probably use a custom metadata provider to handle this for you.

You should check out [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/12/24/introducing-fluent-metadataprovider-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted, but I'd say this doesn't pass the link-only answer sniff test were the link to die (as is currently the case btw).  This is a signpost, perhaps a good one, but the users will still need to go off site to implement.  Consider providing more inline detail or converting to a comment, or accepting the errant vote here and there.

Comment: Which of course is EXACTLY what happened, as that link is dead now.