# How to hanlde this validation dillemma in DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a class structure that looks like this:

```
class Person
{
public virtual string FirstName {get;set;}
public virtual string LastName {get;set;}
public virtual Address HomeAddress {get;set;}
}

class Address
{
public virtual string Street {get;set;}
public virtual string City {get;set;}
public virtual string State {get;set;}
public virtual string ZipCode {get;set;}
public virtual string Country {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have the idea of a person with Required Address and a person that uses the RequiredAddress... so I have my new "Required" address looking like:

```
class RequiredAddress
: Address
{
[Required]
public override string Street {...}
[Required]
public override string City {...}
[Required]
public override string State {...}
[Required]
public override string ZipCode {...}
[Required]
public override string Country {...}
}
```

but when I just newed up an instance of RequiredAddress into the Address field of my RequiredPerson address, MVC couldn't seem to detect the [Required] tags, and I wound up having to do this:

```
class PersonRequiredAddress
    : Person
{
public new RequiredAddress Address {get;set;}
}
```

Now, because we had to do this, we wound up having to re-do our DAL to handle the differences in objects... which feels like a miserable code smell to me.  Can anyone provide a better solution to this quandary we face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change `Person` to be `class Person<TAddress> where TAddress : Address`?  Then `class PersonRequiredAdderss : Person<RequiredAddresss>`.

Comment: I could, but in this instance "Person" is being used as a concrete class, as well as "PersonRequiredAddress"... let me see how that works.

Comment: Yes.. Yes.. I think that'll work.  Heh.. should have realized that one.  thx @cadrell0

Comment: I'm leaving this as the answer, but the issue I run into is in the mapping of the objects.  I can't seem to return a generic IList<Person<TAddress>> since PersonRequiredAddress doesn't seem to want to fit in the IList

Comment: To Clarify this... I am trying to get a repository to return me either 1) a Person<TAddress> or 2) a List<Person<TAddress>> where TAddress could be either Address -OR- RequiredAddress.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at dynamicly attaching dataannotations

Someone else had that question got answered here
[DataAnnotations dynamically attaching attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607247/dataannotations-dynamically-attaching-attributes)

Comment: I think that is outside the scope of what I need to be honest.