# MVC custom display attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have written custom attribute for DisplayName as follows.

```
namespace CRM.Model
{
    public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        private readonly string resourcekey;

        public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceId)
            : base(GetMessageFromResource(resourceId))
        { 

        }

        public static string GetMessageFromResource(string resourceId)
        {
            // My Localization logic
            return LocalizationResourceProvider.Current.GetString(resourceId);
        }       
    }
}
```

When model is loaded/initiated for the first time the above custom attribute class is called successfully.

But if, I will post back the page then, it doesn't get called.

For example when I change my language from English to French. it still displays the English content.

Why it is so ? How can I solve this issue ? Can we load the Model data explicitly

Comment: Yo do realise there is a localised System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute which can be used [Display(ResourceType = typeof(yourResxClass), Name = "ResourceName")] .

Comment: Can you please give me some example of this ? I dont want to directly access Resources.Resources. it should get called from my custom logic

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is setting the language in the constructor. That is why it only works when the model is loaded / initiated for the first time. Not sure how the rest of your solution works, but you need to run the localization logic in other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your attribute on application start up, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607247/dataannotations-dynamically-attaching-attributes) similar thread.